# Warnings and Mistakes of a XCode Project to a Text File

Tags: ios, xcode

I am working in q burst tech. We have a sonar for quality checking. Now we are indeed of developing ios plugin, no need to write the whole code. Actually what I think is with the help of a code analyzer fetch all warnings and put those to sonar for displaying. 

I want to know how can I can get full log files contains all warnings and mistakes of a Xcode project to a text file. Please help me with your valuable suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `xcodebuild` from the command line and pipe `stderr` to a file using:

```
$ xcodebuild 2> errors.txt
```